# C# - Method for writing xml

Tags: c#, xml

I have products in a class that I want to save in a XML file, the products is devided into categoris and I would like to save my products in a XML file formatet like below examlple. Products for category 1 writes under category one and products for category 2 under category two.

Hwo can I write a method that dose that?
Thanks in advance.

```
<Categories>
  <Category ID="1">
    <CategoryName>Categoriname1</CategoryName> 
    <Description>drinks, coffees, beers, ales</Description> 
    <Products>
      <Product>
        <ProductName>Coffe</ProductName> 
        <QuantityPerUnit>15 boxes x 60 bags</QuantityPerUnit> 
        <UnitPrice>25</UnitPrice> 
        <UnitsInStock>3</UnitsInStock> 
        <UnitsOnOrder>0</UnitsOnOrder> 
      </Product>
      <Product>
        <ProductName>Chang</ProductName> 
        <QuantityPerUnit>24 - 12 oz bottles</QuantityPerUnit> 
        <UnitPrice>19</UnitPrice> 
        <UnitsInStock>17</UnitsInStock> 
        <UnitsOnOrder>40</UnitsOnOrder> 
      </Product>
    </Products>
  </Category>
  <Category ID="2">
    <CategoryName>Condiments</CategoryName> 
    <Description>spreads, and seasonings</Description> 
    <Products>
      <Product>
        <ProductName>Productname</ProductName>
```

Comment: Good question :) .. i had this same problem some time ago. By I managed to deserialize my objects straight from the database (returned xml from a stored proc) and fed it to a constructor that accepted the xml string then i overrode the ToString to go back the other way. I think i should have implemented iserializable though and use tobias approach (linq to Xml is awesome and really simple to use).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx). Assume you have these classes (where I have removed some properties to simplify the example):

```
class Category {
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public String Name { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product {
  public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

You can create some test data:

```
var categories = new[] {
  new Category {
    Id = 1,
    Name = "Category 1",
    Products = new[] {
      new Product { Name = "Coffee" },
      new Product { Name = "Chang" }
    }
  },
  new Category {
    Id = 2,
    Name = "Condiments",
    Products = new[] {
      new Product { Name = "Product 1" }
    }
  }
};
```

You can then create an `XDocument` from the test data:

```
var xmlDocument = new XDocument(
  new XElement(
    "Categories",
    categories.Select(
      c => new XElement(
        "Category",
        new XAttribute("ID", c.Id),
        new XElement("CategoryName", c.Name),
        new XElement("Products",
          c.Products.Select(
            p => new XElement(
              "Product",
              new XElement("ProductName", p.Name)
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
);
```

To save it to a file you can use the `Save` method:

```
xmlDocument.Save("Categories.xml");
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But how do I do if I want to add a product under a specific time, because if new products comes in then I would like to add each product under its categori. How do I do that?

Comment: In your project you should have classes similar to `Category` and `Product` and you should be able to add a new `Product` to a `Category`. In my example I opted for a very simple solution where products in a category are stored in an array which requires the entire array to be replaced when new products are added to a category. However, as long as your `Category` class exposes an `IEnumerable<Product>` collection you can use LINQ to XML as demonstrated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **LINQ to XML**:

http://www.hookedonlinq.com/LINQtoXML5MinuteOverview.ashx

Comment: +1 For a quick and dirty solution i would use this in an override of the .ToString() method in my objects. For a more compliant approach implement iserializable and put this code in the serialize method.

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ to XML.

your example would start off like...

```
  var root = new XElement("Categories",
                    new XElement("Category", 
                          new XAttribute("ID",1),
                          new XElement("CategoryName", "Categoriname1")
                    )
               );
```

Your intellisense should help you get the rest

Answer (score 1):

You need to serialize those classes. Create classes marked with Serializable attribute and use XmlSerializer

example:

http://www.dotnetjohn.com/articles.aspx?articleid=173

Comment: `SerializableAttribute` has absolutely nothing to do with XML serialization.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`XmlSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) class or the [`XmlDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) class or the [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) class or even the [`XmlTextWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter.aspx) class.

Answer (score 1):

You may also like to simply serialise the object(s) that you have. You may write a method like this:

```
public static bool WriteToXMLFile(string fullFileNameWithPath, Object obj, Type ObjectType)
    {
        TextWriter xr = null;
        try
        {
            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(ObjectType);
            xr = new StreamWriter(fullFileNameWithPath);
            ser.Serialize(xr, obj);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            if(xr != null)
                xr.Close();
        }
        return true;
    }
```